# PrototypeJS Element.prototype.appendChild issue

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Due to Ajax loaded content, I had to change a function from:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded',function() {    
    $$('.userListHeaderCell').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {       
        this.toggleClassName('desc');        
        var colnumber = this.up().childElements().indexOf(this);        
        var content = this.up(2); 
        sortColumn(content, colnumber, this.hasClassName('desc'));    
    });
});
```

TO:

```
document.observe('click', function(e, el) {  
    if (el = e.findElement('.userListHeaderCell.sortable')) { 
        el.toggleClassName('desc');        
        var colnumber = el.up().childElements().indexOf(el);        
        var content = el.up(2); 
        sortColumn(content, colnumber, el.hasClassName('desc'));   
    }
});
```

The sortColumn looks like:

```
function sortColumn(content, colnumber, desc) {    
    content.select('.userListRow').sort(function(a,b){        
        var atext = a.down(colnumber).innerHTML.stripTags().toLowerCase();        
        var btext = b.down(colnumber).innerHTML.stripTags().toLowerCase();        
        return atext.localeCompare(btext) * (desc ? -1 : 1);    
    }).each(Element.prototype.appendChild, content);
}
```

The toggle and colnumber work and content is an object HTMLDivElement, but it seems that I need to convert the content variable or use another function, but not sure what in the sortColumn.  The error I get is:

"Could not convert JavaScript argument" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: https://www.someurl.com/scripts/prototype.js ::  :: line 804" data: no]

What do I need to change in order to make this work?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Error in IE shows:
Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined prototype.js, line 804 character 9

I believe the issue is with Element.prototype.appendChild

Tried adding Element.extend(content), but doesn't seem to help.

Example data:

```html
<div id="contentbox_Users" class="userList">
    <div class="userListHeader">
        <div class="userListHeaderCell col1 sortable">First Name</div>
        <div class="userListHeaderCell col2 sortable">Last Name</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentbox_People">
        <div class="userListRow">
            <div class="userListCell col1">John</div>
            <div class="userListCell col2">Smith</div>
        </div>
        <div class="userListRow">
            <div class="userListCell col1">Bob</div>
            <div class="userListCell col2">Ray</div>
        </div>
        <div class="userListRow">
            <div class="userListCell col1">Fred</div>
            <div class="userListCell col2">Jones</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a border on the CSS for "desc" and see what element is being selected when the class name is added. Seeing what's going on may help.

Comment: It puts it on the First Name or Last Name, whichever is selected.  I believe the issue is with Element.prototype.appendChild.  Not sure how to change that though.

Comment: For anyone who is curious, see [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6932677/471559) for some background and a working jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is my code that is failing I should have a go.

The line,

```
}).each(Element.prototype.appendChild, content);
```

is a shorthand way of saying,

```
}).each(function(row) {
    content.appendChild(row);
});
```

You can try it that way to see if things are better. I don't recognise the error but a quick google suggests it is from Firefox and relates to passing a non-element to a native function that expects one. In situations such as this I tend to stick lots of `console.log(...)` calls everywhere (and press F12 in Firefox) and see what happens. Logging the array *should* show all the rows as HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks, that is working, however it is putting the rows outside on the same level as contentbox_Users.  I can fix that though.